# I have a fixed div that I am using jquery to fade out on scroll. It works fine but if I am half way down and refersh the page the div shows up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a landing page with a full `height` and `width` div and a background image. I am floating a fixed div in front and fading it out as the user scrolls up. It's great unless someone refreshes the page when they're half way down, then the fixed div shows up again. How do I only show div if it's "above the fold"?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function( $ ){
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos <= 0) {
        $(".blue_bar").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $(".blue_bar").fadeOut();
    }
});
 
 });
</script>
```

```css
.blue_bar {
    width:75%;
    max-width:900px;
    padding: 40px 65px 40px 65px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:95px;
    right:55px;
    background-color:rgba(0,105,170,0.8);
}
```

Comment: Add your function after page loaded `$(document).ready(function() {........}`

Comment: You could add another listener onload to check the current scroll position, and show/hide depending on the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because your code for fading out doesn't get executed if the page reloads.
So what you can do is enclose that logic inside a function and call it on page load as well as on scroll.

**HTML**

```
<div class="blue_bar" style="display:none;">
    blah
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    let processFade = function(){
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollPos <= 0) {
            $(".blue_bar").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(".blue_bar").fadeOut();
        }
    };
    $(window).on("scroll load", function () {
        processFade();
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        processFade();
    });
});
```

**Update:** "*The div shows up, then quickly disappears again.*"

The solution is pretty simple, Just start out with a hidden `div` :) Updated the code to reflect the same.

Comment: This works great except for if I reload the page after scrolling down. The div shows up, then quickly disappears again. I've tried using .delay but that doesn't seem to effect the "flash" of the div.  Can you give me some ideas on where to look next?